# How to test an if sentence inside useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs, enzyme, use-effect

I'm trying to test an `if` sentence inside a `useEffect` which main dependency, `riskSelection`, comes from a `useSelector` from `react-redux` library. Jest coverage indicates line 20-21 is missing.

`App.tsx`

```
function App(): JSX.Element {
  const riskSelection = useAppSelector(selectRiskSelection);
  const {save} = useActions({...riskSelectorActions});
  const risks: Risk = risks_levels;
  const [data, setData] = useState<Data[]>();

  const width = 450,
    height = 450,
    margin = 40;
  const radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2 - margin;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (typeof riskSelection !== 'undefined') {      // line 20
      setData(Object.values(risks[riskSelection]));  // line 21
    }
  }, [riskSelection, risks]);

  return (
    <div>
        <ul className={style.riskSelectorUl}>
          {new Array(10).fill(0).map((v, i: number) => (
            <li
              className={Number(riskSelection) === i + 1 ? style.selected : ''}
              onClick={() => save({riskSelection: `${i + 1}`})}
              key={i}
            >
              {i + 1}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      {data && (
        <PieSVG
          data={data}
          width={width}
          height={height}
          innerRadius={100}
          outerRadius={radius}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My test should verify if PieSVG has been rendered or not. In order to do so I have to simulate a change in `riskSelection`. This is where I need help.

`App.test.tsx`

```
jest.mock('../utils/redux/hooks');
import * as reduxHooks from '../utils/redux/hooks';

describe('App', () => {
  let wrapper: any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest
      .spyOn(reduxHooks, 'useAppSelector')
      .mockImplementation((f) => f({riskSelector: {riskSelection: undefined}}));
    wrapper = shallow(<Dummy />);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });

  it('shows pie chart', () => {    
    reduxHooks.useAppSelector(() => '1');
    expect(wrapper.find(PieSVG)).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```

I use `mockImplementation` to try to change `riskSelector` but that just initializes my redux state.

The user trigger this change of redux state when it click on a `<li />` which uses `save` action.

Maybe I should not make my UI changes so dependent on a `useEffect`?

`hook.ts`

```
import {TypedUseSelectorHook, useSelector} from 'react-redux';

import type {RootState} from './store';

export const useAppSelector: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState> = useSelector;
```

Comment: You didn't use the `save` action. If it's an unrelated code, please delete it.

Comment: @slideshowp2 I just added the part where it's used.